# The polynomial $p(x)$ satisfies $p(1) = 210$ and $(x + 10) p(2x) = 8(x - 4) p(x + 6)$ for all real numbers $x.$ Find $p(10).$

Tags: polynomials

> The polynomial $p(x)$ satisfies $p(1) = 210$ and $$(x + 10) p(2x) = 8(x - 4) p(x + 6)$$for all real numbers $x.$ Find $p(10).$

Noting that for $x=4$ we get that $p(8)=0$, for $x=2$ we have that $p(4)=0$ and for $x=-2$ we have that $p(-4)=0$ thus $$p(x)=(x-8)(x+4)(x-4)g(x)$$ for some polynomial $g$.

Now the given equation becomes $$(x + 10)(2x - 8)(2x - 4)(2x + 4) g(2x) = 8(x - 4)(x - 2)(x + 2)(x + 10) g(x + 6).$$

I however cannot see why would this equation simplify to $g(2x)=g(x+6)$? Expanding all the terms this could probably be seen, but it's quite cumbersome to expand these all out. Is there an easier way to see this?

Comment: Equating the leading coefficients gives $n=3$.

Comment: Take out the factor of $2$ from three of the factors on the left-hand side, and you will see that the four factors cancel out exactly.

Comment: For those puzzled by @MichaelHoppe's comment (as I was at first), $n$ is the degree of $p$.

Comment: And if you compare the leading coefficients in the final equation, you get that $g$ is constant! So now it's easy.

Comment: Can I just "take out" the $2$'s from $$(x + 10)(2x - 8)(2x - 4)(2x + 4) g(2x)$$ from each of the factors and get that $$(x + 10)(2x - 8)(2x - 4)(2x + 4) g(2x) = (x + 10)2(x - 4)2(x - 2)2(x + 2) = 8(x + 10)(x - 4)(x - 2)(x + 2)$$? @TonyK

Comment: Umm...yes. Yes you can.

Comment: Okay. Somehow I was thinking that the multiplication with $g(2x)$ would compromise this. Brain fog...